# Cairo-Dock dock launch issue

Tags: 12.04, command-line, cairo-dock

Recently i installed Cairo-Dock,which is really good .But my main concern is  everytime i want to lunch the dock , i need it to open through terminal.After launching i can't use terminal for any other purpose and also when i try to close terminal it will tell .. "terminal is executing some process do you want to end" and when i close the terminal .. dock also will get closed .Now i need Cairo-Dock to work like all other app .I need to open the dock through GUI,not through terminal.please help me out for this.

PS: i am new to ubuntu, and  i'm using 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cairo Dock have an option in its preferences as add as startup application. Its doesnt matter for the first time how you going to launch it but if you made the select as a startup program then from next restart you will have it as auto start and you never have to start again manually.

So you can do it as right click on it / Cairo-Dock Menu / Launch the dock at startup.

**With out opening dock even** , you can set it to auto start with

```
cairo-dock -o
```

If you cant find it in the cairo dock preferences then you can do it from the system startup applications.  click at the system settings there you can find startup applications and click add button and add cairo dock as startup application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash(window key),and search for cairo-dock.Now you open the dock through GUI.